# What's the better way to represent this multidimensional data?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, orm, relational-database, database

We are trying to represent this data in a web application.What will be the appropriate way to represent this data? We thought of using relational structure but data are hierarchical in nature.Is it better to use MongoDB in this scenario ?
[image: health data]

Comment: A hierarchy is a relation.  Relational databases can handle your data effectively, and IMO are better for data integrity and ease of querying.

Comment: Hello @reaanb ,Do you have links to some example schema that I can look at?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database.  My preferred method is the simple adjacency list model (i.e. parent and child key columns) complemented with closure tables when recursive queries aren't available or efficient.

Comment: is this all data you need to store - as it looks simple from that table, I'm thinking what other analytics's you will have to perform on that structure?

Comment: Hello @profesor79 , Yes. That's the only data.  The problem is that columns like NFHS 1996, NDHS 2001 is variable i.e. more sources could be added later such as NDHS 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment mongo dynamic schemas is a perfect solution.

let assume that we have our document structured like this:

```
report {
    _id...
    documentBycode {
        _id : "G8",
        dataSource,
        remarks,
        fields : [{
                indicator : "sucide",
                baseline {
                    data,
                    year,
                    source
                },
                milestone[{
                        year : 2017,
                        value : 15
                    }, {}

                ]

                ...
                ...
                fields : [{
                        name : "nfhs1996",
                        value : "n/a",
                        order : 1 /* this is not mandatory*/
                    }, {
                        name : "ndhs2011",
                        value : "n/a",
                        order : 2
                    }
                ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

then you can add/modify elements as needed inside [arrays] and always get report data by retrieving only one document from datastore.

What's also could be interesting you could have mulitple diffrent reports structures stored in same collection - so you can literally store full ViewModel  data ***AS IS***

Any comment welcome!

Comment: How easy would it be to query the data then? I don't have working experience with MongoDB?

Comment: @ShresthaRohit quering is similar like in sql - you need to know id of document or specific field value